# How to count total occurrence from one table with another table

Tags: sql, join

Table 1:

| ID | Name | Type | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | TR1092 | A | 02-12-2019 | 02-12-2019 |
| 120 | TR1096 | A | 02-16-2019 | 02-16-2019 |
| 101 | TR1096 | A | 02-22-2019 | 02-22-2019 |
| 34 | TR1092 | A | 02-22-2019 | 02-22-2019 |
| 1 | DR9209 | A | 02-12-2019 | 02-12-2019 |
| 20 | DR9209 | A | 02-13-2019 | 02-13-2019 |
| 67 | DR8703 | A | 02-11-2019 | 02-11-2019 |
| 99 | DR8703 | A | 02-11-2019 | 02-11-2019 |
| 145 | FR2435 | A | 02-11-2019 | 02-11-2019 |
| 147 | FR2345 | A | 02-16-2019 | 02-16-2019 |
| 148 | FR2347 | A | 02-16-2019 | 02-16-2019 |

Table 2 (`SessID` matches with `ID` in `Table 1`):

| SessID | Action |
| --- | --- |
| 090 | Push |
| 090 | Pull |
| 090 | Push |
| 120 | Push |
| 034 | Pull |
| 034 | Pull |
| 148 | Pull |
| 148 | Kick |
| 148 | Pull |
| 020 | Pull |
| 067 | Pull |
| 067 | Push |
| 067 | Punch |
| 001 | Pull |
| 147 | Kick |
| 147 | Push |
| 148 | Pull |
| 099 | Kick |
| 099 | Push |

I wrote a query which gives me a total count for each `Name` in `Table 1`:

```
Select
    CASE
        WHEN T1.Name LIKE 'TR%' THEN 'Town Row'
        WHEN T1.Name LIKE 'DR%' THEN 'Doctor Row'
        WHEN T1.Name LIKE 'FR%' THEN 'Fruit Row'
    END AS Name
    , COUNT(*) AS 'NameTotals'
From
    NamedRecord T1
Where
    T1.Type = 'A'
    AND
    T1.Start >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(Month,0,Getdate(),0)
    AND
    T1.End <= DATEADD(Day,1,Getdate())
Group by
    (
        CASE
            WHEN T1.Name LIKE 'TR%' THEN 'Town Row'
            WHEN T1.Name LIKE 'DR%' THEN 'Doctor Row'
            WHEN T1.Name LIKE 'FR%' THEN 'Fruit Row'
        END
    )
Order By
    Name
```

Result:

| Name | NameTotals |
| --- | --- |
| Town Row | 4 |
| Doctor Row | 4 |
| Fruit Row | 3 |

How can I update my query so I have a column:

- `WhatHappTotals` - Count total number of actions by matching `SessID` in `Table 2` to `ID` and then to `Name` in `Table 1`

Result will look like this:

| Name | NameTotals | WhatHappTotals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Town Row | 4 | 6 |
| Doctor Row | 4 | 8 |
| Fruit Row | 3 | 6 |

Comment: Consider using  select table1name, nametotals, whathapptotals  from (select count (id) as NameTotals, substring  (table1.name,1,2) as table1name, session  from table 1 group by substring  (table1.name,1,2) , session) a  join (select count (id) as WhatHappTotals,  session  from table2 group by session )  b on a.session = b.session      You can work in your case statement from there

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE One (
    ID    int        NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name  varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    Type  varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    Start datetime   NOT NULL,
    End   datetime   NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Two (
    SessId int        NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Action varchar(5) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT Two_FK_One FOREIGN KEY (SessId) REFERENCES One (ID)
)

SELECT Name, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS NameCount,
    COUNT(*) AS WhatHappTotal
FROM (
    SELECT o.ID, o.Type, o.Start, o.End
        CASE 
            WHEN o.Name LIKE 'TR%' THEN 'Town Row'
            WHEN o.Name LIKE 'DR%' THEN 'TDoctor Row'
            WHEN o.Name LIKE 'FR%' THEN 'TFruit Row'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS Name,
        t.Action
    FROM One o
        INNER JOIN Two t ON t.SessId = o.ID
) T
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Thank you, but your query would require me to have the `CONSTRAINT` in Table 2...

Comment: No it doesn't; you can still `INNER JOIN` without having a `FOREIGN KEY`. The FK just helps defend against unexpected results.

Comment: I was able to tweak it a bit but i got it to work finally, thank you! I do have a question though, would I be able to get an Average in table 1 by day?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN NR.Name LIKE 'TR%' THEN 'Town Row'
        WHEN NR.Name LIKE 'DR%' THEN 'Doctor Row'
        WHEN NR.Name LIKE 'FR%' THEN 'Fruit Row'
    END AS Name,
    COUNT(NR.ID) AS "NameTotals",
    COUNT(SI.SessID) AS "WhatHappTotals"
FROM NameRecord AS NR
JOOIN SessionId AS S1 on SI.SessID = NR.ID
    AND
    NR.Type = 'A'
    AND
    NR.Start >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(Month,0,Getdate(),0)
    AND
    NR.End <= DATEADD(Day,1,Getdate())
Group By Name
Order By Name;
```

Can you try and see if it works or not?

Comment: Sorry this didn't work... Thanks.